# Do we need a tag for boarding?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently the [cattery](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cattery) tag was created. If we want to continue using it, it should be generalized. I'm not sure what the proper term would be, or if it would be covered in [vacation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacation).

Answer (score 5):

[cattery](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cattery) should be synonymized with [boarding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boarding) (so that it will cover all animals)

Comment: This makes major sense to me... :)

Comment: Is "doggery" a "thing"?

Comment: I can't speak for other parts of the world, but in Britain we'd talk about "kennels", which brings about its own ambiguity in the context of this question.

Comment: @ClickRick - "kennels" is used in the U.S. too,  It's usually a more-specific boarding, so I'd synonymize it with "boarding" as well, if it was to be used.

Answer (score -4):

[cattery](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cattery) should be synonymized with [vacation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vacation). We don't need a specific tag to cover boarding facilities.

Comment: It should not go to vacation, because boarding is sometimes a one day/daily occurrence.

Comment: May also be done for non-vacation reasons. For example, when I bought my house, the former owners boarded their pets at the kennel down the road for a weekend in order to finish the packing and moving out.

Comment: And sometimes your pets come along on vacation.